# get python expression intermediate execution state?

Tags: python, boolean, expression

long story short, I am building a rule engine prototype to filtering web request logs.

e.g.

The web request logs was like millions rows of json data like:

```
{"ip": "2.3.4.5", "user": {"register_time": 1494899081.527145, "gender": "F"}}
```

If operator could specified some rules in our system like

```
ip == '1.2.4.5' and (user.register_time - now < 3600 or user.gender == 'F')
```

If a certain row from the log matches the rule, the engine would take the the row to the next series of actions.

Please note that the `now` variable was provided by our rule engine. The rule engine has the capability of providing several system variables and functions.

The prototype I am using is to use `eval()` method in python to transform rules to actual python code and examine logs row by row. (Yeah I knew `eval()` was bad but remember this is a prototype)

My question is, in the above example, If a certain row was a match to the rule, I want to tell which exact conditions are met. Is it just `user.register_time - now < 3600` is `True`, or just `user.gender == 'F'` was `True`? (Or both?)

Currently I am using `ast.iter_fields` to find all `ast.Name` and `ast.Attribute` and use `eval()` again for their value, but for one row of data I had to run eval() several times it feels kind of redundant.

Is it possible to introspect back how a value was calculated from last line of code, like a simple `A and (B or C)` bool expression above. Can we well find out which part was evaluated and by which value?

PLus, for `or` expressions can we tell which part was omitted because it was short-circuited by prior conditionals?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved by [MacroPy](https://github.com/lihaoyi/macropy#tracing).

```
from macropy.tracing import macros, trace
with trace:
    sum = 0
    for i in range(0, 5):
        sum = sum + 5

# sum = 0
# for i in range(0, 5):
#     sum = sum + 5
# range(0, 5) -> [0, 1, 2, 3, 4]
# sum = sum + 5
# sum + 5 -> 5
# sum = sum + 5
# sum + 5 -> 10
# sum = sum + 5
# sum + 5 -> 15
# sum = sum + 5
# sum + 5 -> 20
# sum = sum + 5
# sum + 5 -> 25
```